# Program not displaying splash screen image when run in IDE

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class SplashScr extends JWindow implements Runnable
{
public void run()
  {
  Container c;
  ImageIcon SplashScr = new ImageIcon("lsl1.jpg");
  JLabel SplashScrLabel = new JLabel(SplashScr);
  //Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
  //Color c1 = Color.RED;
  //SplashScrLabel.setBorder(new LineBorder(c1,3));

  c = getContentPane();
  c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  c.add(SplashScrLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  setSize(1100,300);
  setLocation(100,300);
  show();  
  }
}
```

I am giving splash screen call from an object from the main file. code is working fine. I can see the splash screen's boundaries but not the image. When I run my program through command prompt instead of eclipse it's working fine. please help in simple steps.

Comment: Where is the image located?  If it's located within the `src` or `resource` directory, you will need to use `getClass().getResource(...)` to read it, like every other answer to this question.  Use `ImageIO.read` to read the images, it throws an `IOException` when the image can't be read for some reason. See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: *"please help in simple steps."*  You seem to be mistaking this Q&A site for a help desk or us for tutors..

Comment: BTW - Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.